# laravel 4.2 Composer install error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Whenever I try to composer install I keep getting an error. Below is what I see on my terminal. I've tried to lower the cashier version. Ive tried on another laravel project. I keep getting the same error, Not sure what is going on.

The composer.json

```
{
"name": "andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site",
"description": "Laravel 4 Starter Site",
"keywords": ["laravel", "Starter Site"],
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Andrew Elkins",
        "homepage": "http://www.andrewelkins.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "~4.2",
    "zizaco/confide": "~3.2",
    "zizaco/entrust": "~1.2",
    "bllim/datatables": "~1.3",
    "laravel/cashier": "~2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "way/generators": "~2.6",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
    "summerstreet/woodling": "~0.1.6",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "~1.11"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/library",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/library"
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Acme": "app/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

The error on terminal

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.0 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.1 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.2 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.3 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.4 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.5 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.6 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - laravel/cashier v2.0.7 requires stripe/stripe-php ~1.9 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v1.10.1, v1.11.0, v1.12.0, v1.13.0, v1.13.1, v1.14.1, v1.15.0, v1.16.0, v1.17.0, v1.17.1, v1.17.2, v1.17.3, v1.17.4, v1.17.5, v1.18.0, v1.9.0, v1.9.1].
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.9.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.9.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.18.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.17.5 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.17.4 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.17.3 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.17.2 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.17.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.17.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.16.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.15.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.14.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.13.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.13.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.12.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.11.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - stripe/stripe-php v1.10.1 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/cashier ~2.0.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/cashier[v2.0.0, v2.0.1, v2.0.2, v2.0.3, v2.0.4, v2.0.5, v2.0.6, v2.0.7].
```

Comment: specify OS you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install and enable `ext-curl` on your system.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Answer (score 0):

**The quick solution for this error**

**First install required php extensions**

*next run this command*

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

**This command not consider operating system or platform**